# chapter title versus tree presentation

Tags: documentation-generator

I am writing a document.

It has multiple chapters with titles.

e.g.

```
1. Hardware
1.1. CPU
1.1.1 RISC
       blabla
1.1.2 CISC
       blabla
1.2. Memory
...
```

The chapters form a soft of tree.

Is there a software that would present me the document as a tree with the text in the leaves?

Comment: What would be the required output format and what would be the input format?

Comment: I can accept a lot of different formats.

Comment: What OS must it run on? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions? Any other features the software must have?

Answer (score 1):

Try `TeX`. It generates a TOC automatically.